# What is the effect in the time when we change input size from $n$ to $n+1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is the effect in the time when we change input size from $n$ to $n+1$ given that the number of milliseconds the algorithm needs to solve the problem with input size $n$ is:

1. $f(n)=n^3$
2. $f(n)=2^n$

Express the answer in the simplest form possible.

For 1, if we choose the difference, we would get,

$$f(n+1)-f(n) = 3n^2+3n+1$$

For 2, if we choose the difference, we would get,

$$f(n+1)-f(n) = 2^n$$

For 1, if we choose the ration, we would get,

$$f(n+1)-f(n) = \frac{n^3(1+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{3}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3})}{n^3}$$
$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~= (1+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{3}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3})$$

**Question 1:** difference above is $<2$, so I guess the ratio should be used here instead of a difference $f(n+1)-f(n) = 3n^2+3n+1$ as it gives us a better estimate, but the answer I found online uses difference instead of the ratio.

For 2, if we choose the ratio, we would get,

$$f(n+1)-f(n) = \frac{2^{n+1}}{2^n}=2$$

which is a better estimate than the difference that gives $f(n+1)-f(n) = 2^n$.

**Question 2:** the ratio here is better to estimate the time in the simplest form possible. So the question is, with this kind of question, I have to experiment with both difference and ratio to see which one gives a better estimate or is there a better way to select if I should use either difference or ratio to express the answer in the simplest form?

Comment: When you use the ratio (not ration, that means something entirely different) different, you must write it as as a ratio: $f(n+1)/f(n)$.  If you write $f(n+1)-f(n)$ then you're talking about the difference.  As to your second question, it's not  clear to me how you decided that the ratio is "better" for the cubic.

Comment: @saulspatz. As $n \to \infty $, then we will get at most $1+$ value near 0, which is in total $<2$.